# Variance Ratio Test in R

Tags: programming, variance, auto-correlation, ratio

I would like to conduct a variance ratio test for a financial time series in order to examine whether I can apply the square root rule for the variance with the software R.
I used the Automatic Variance Ratio Test `vrtest::Auto.Vr` and got a statistic of `-0.01`. Now I am wondering, is that the z-score, which is distributed standard normal under the Null hypothesis, that this ratio is `1` (or equivalent that there is no autocorrelation)? It is not specified in the describtion, I just found this:

```
Usage:
Auto.VR(y)
Arguments:
y financial return time series
Value:
stat Automatic variance ratio test statistic
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: the test statistic's distribution is $N(0,1)$

**A bit more information about the Automatic Variance Ratio Test:**

$H_0$: ${\Delta}r_t$ is serially **un**correlated (where ${\Delta}r_t=r_t-r_{t-1}$)

$H_1$: ${\Delta}r_t$ **is** serially correlated

The test statistic is $VR=\sqrt{T/l}[\hat{VR}(l)-1]/\sqrt{2} \quad {\xrightarrow{d}} \quad N(0,1)$

The $d$ over the arrow is important, i.e. the $VR$ *converges* in distribution to standard normal (hence $d$ does not imply the convergence in mean square or convergence in probability) as $T$, $l$ and $T/l$ approach infinity.
The $l$ is the lag truncation point. The paper has detail on formulae for both $VR$ and $l$.

Final note: the test is two sided.

Comment: Isn't convergence in distribution the weakest among the three forms of converncege that you mention, so that it cannot imply the other two (while the other two imply the former)? See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4).

Comment: Absolutely! It goes m.s. -> p -> d. That is a typo, now fixed.